# Linked List Using Classes

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I have created a linked list `class VW` with a function `Build` to add nodes to the list. However, when I run the code to build my linked list, the `Build` function throws an "access violation" error. The error is thrown by the call `tmp->NextObj(`) in the `Build` function.

If the object of `class VW` is newly created and the `Build` is called for the first time, then the condition `if(tmp==NULL)` in the `Build` function should be true, and hence the program should not enter the `else` section during the first call to `Build`. What am I missing here? Could you please help.

```
   class VW
{
    World_Obj *head;
public:
    void Build(...);

};
 void VW::Build(...)
    {
        World_Obj *newObj;
        newObj = new World_Obj;
        newObj->SetData(...);
        newObj->SetNext(NULL);

        World_Obj *tmp;
        tmp = this->head;

        if (tmp == NULL)
            this->head = newObj;
        else
        {
            while (tmp->NextObj() != NULL)
            {
                tmp = tmp->NextObj();
            }
            tmp->SetNext(newObj);
        }
    }

int main()
{
    VW *g_w;    
    g_w = new VW;

          /* Reading arguments from input file*/

    g_w->Build(...);

}
```

Comment: Create a minimal example and don't use pictures that only contain text, they can't be indexed and searched.

Comment: Did you try to catch the crash in a debugger to help you locate where it happens?

Comment: Yes, the error occurs due to the call to tmp->NextObj() in the else section of the Build function. However, the first time Build is called, head should be null and the if condition should hold true. I am not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. I have updated the question based on your comments.

Comment: How do we know that `head` should be a null pointer? You don't show it being initialized anywhere. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: What exactly does `NextObj()` do? It probably increments a pointer to the current object in `World_Obj`. I guess the problem is that you call this function twice in your loop.

Comment: `class World_Obj
{
 ...
 World_Obj *next; 
public: 
        World_Obj* NextObj() { return next; } 
};`
NextObj() returns a pointer to the next node in the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the missing constructor in the class VW,

`VW(){ head=NULL;}`

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *big* problem:

```
tmp = this->head;

...

while (tmp->NextObj() != NULL)
{
    tmp = tmp->NextObj();
}
tmp->SetNext(newObj);

...

delete tmp;
```

When the loop ends and after you do `tmp->SetNext(newObj)` then `tmp` will point to the second to last node in the list. Which you then promptly destroy by deleting it.

That means your list will now somewhere contain a node that no longer exist, and attempting to dereference it will lead to *undefined behavior* and most likely a crash.

The solution is simply to not delete `tmp`.

Comment: Thanks Joachim for the quick response. I removed the delete statement. However, I am still facing my earlier issue.